# how to awk if with multiple line condition

Tags: awk

i have some problem with our log , need some alert if have some match condition.

some log below condition :

```
2019-07-20|20:25|sorry system error|183
2019-07-20|20:25|Internal Error|8
2019-07-20|20:25|System Busy|1
```

my expectation if field `$4 >= 100`, it will `print $0` and sent alert with `curl` condition below :

```
curl -X GET "http://x.x.x.x:5000/submit_fajar.php?msg=print $0+`hostname`+time_`date +%d%h%y_%H.%M.%S`"
```

i already tried with condition below but still confused how to `curl` with `print $0`

```
cat datafiles  | strings | awk -F"|" '{if ($4 > 100)print ""$1","$2",please check have many error respond MFS",$3,"count :",$4;'}''
```

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    curl "...$line..."
done < <(awk '...')
```

btw your awk script:

```
awk -F"|" '{if ($4 > 100)print ""$1","$2",please check have many error respond MFS",$3,"count :",$4;'}''
```

should be:

```
awk -F'|' '$4 > 100{print $1 "," $2 ",please check have many error respond MFS", $3, "count :", $4}'
```

and your curl should probably be something like:

```
hostname="$(hostname)"
now="$(date +'%d%h%y_%H.%M.%S')"
curl -X GET "http://x.x.x.x:5000/submit_fajar.php?msg=\"${line}+${hostname}+${now}\""
```

with the first 2 lines being before the loop so the whole thing should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/env bash

hostname="$(hostname)"
now="$(date +'%d%h%y_%H.%M.%S')"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    curl -X GET "http://x.x.x.x:5000/submit_fajar.php?msg=\"${line}+${hostname}+${now}\""
done < <(cat datafiles | strings | awk -F'|' '$4 > 100{print $1 "," $2 ",please check have many error respond MFS", $3, "count :", $4}')
```

assuming you have a reason for the `cat`.

Comment: hi morton, thanks for reply. script running but have error when sent alert to curl, is it need url encode ? <html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
+ IFS=
+ read -r line

Comment: when trying changes $line with testing success to curl...i think have a issue when sent $line , i tried this script ........#!/bin/bash
hostname="$(hostname)"
now="$(date +'%d%h%y_%H.%M.%S')"
while IFS= read -r line; do
curl -X GET "http://x.x.x.x:5000/telegram/submit_fajar.php?msg=\"testing+${hostname}+${now}\""
done < <(cat test.txt | strings | awk -F'|' '$4 > 100{print $1 "," $2 ",please check have many error respond MFS", $3, "count :", $4}')
~

Comment: I have no idea how your `curl` is supposed to be written, I was just answering your question of how to use awk output in your curl. You'll have to debug the curl command for yourself, start with hard-coded values in a standalone statement outside of the loop.

Comment: no problem...thanks alot for your help morton.

Comment: You're welcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.